# Thead Background Image Overlay

Tags: html, css

I have an html Document with CSS and try the following:
I want to have an Background-Image in `<Thead>`. This Image should be in the Background of the other td´s. Maybe an overlay?

I want to get the following solution (Note: The Image must be in the thead. The other Td must be without an Background-Image)

[image: Example:]

Why should I need it?
We are using an online-built-in-software that converts html outputs in pdf. And the thead is the only markup that repeats on every page. Other solutions for repeating a header doesn't work.

A Background-Image at TBody doesn't work for me, because it doesn't repeat when the pagebrake come.

**Edit: Update with codes and clearify my question**

So Here is a simple code where I start (Thanks to @NickVU)

```html
<style type="text/css"> 

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
  color: yellow
}
thead {
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg");
}

</style>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So at the End, i want to get the following output. (Like the img. above)

```html
<style type="text/css"> 

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  color: yellow
}
table {
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

</style>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note: But the img must be linked at the `thead`

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=thead+background+image+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a minimal reproducible example of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: I am sorry. I just forget it. Thanks for additional information. The Code looks like the from Nick Vu.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

According your requirement update, now I briefly understood your case.

That's impossible to have `background-image` with overflow, BUT we can do it with pseudoelement `::before` on `thead`. Here is an example

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

thead::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**OLD ANSWER**

I think you just simply put it in your CSS

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
thead, tbody {
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif");
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

P/s: I'm using [W3 school image](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif) for the demo. You can replace it with your own image.

Comment: Thanks so far. This is also what i get. The W3 school image should now be in the Background of January, 100, February and 800. But the Image must be linked from Thead.

Comment: I just modified my answer again with `thead, tbody` in CSS. Could you try again and let me know if that's what you're expecting? @RichardZelzner

Comment: Thanks for your modification. But this not what i expect. I change the code as followed: https://codepen.io/RichiZ/pen/jOYbrMy (As you see i changed the img). And this ist what i want to get: https://codepen.io/RichiZ/pen/yLpYJbz But the img must be linked at the <thead> @Nick VU

Comment: So you want that image only on `thead` but fit? @RichardZelzner

Comment: Yes. The Image should Start in `Thead` and end in the others `TD`. Where the end is doesnt matter. If the end of the image is in de middle of `TD` that will be ok. @NickVu

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h2Ld8tsq/ I'm not sure this is the case you expected or not, but the only way we can put background-image for `thead` is using pseudo elements `::before`. Btw, I updated my answer too.